# Performing column & row operations in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Functions such as matrix multiplication perform `column x row` operations and then do a reduction operation. I want to do something similar, but I would like to replace the multiplication and addition operators with something else, such as `max` and `min`. I have something that works but it seems "ugly" at best.

```
# Setup 
a = tf.reshape(tf.range(0.0, 8.0), [4, 2])
b = tf.reshape(tf.range(4.0, 12.0), [2, 4])

# Baseline
tf.matmul(a, b)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 32.,  37.,  42.,  47.],
       [ 56.,  65.,  74.,  83.],
       [ 80.,  93., 106., 119.]], dtype=float32)>

# Can this part be done better?
a_b = tf.reshape(a, [4, 1, 2])
b_b = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(b), [1, 4, 2])

# The result is at least correct
tf.reduce_sum(a_b * b_b, -1)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 32.,  37.,  42.,  47.],
       [ 56.,  65.,  74.,  83.],
       [ 80.,  93., 106., 119.]], dtype=float32)>

# And it can be extended to be generic
tf.reduce_min(tf.maximum(a_b, b_b), -1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [4., 5., 6., 7.],
       [6., 6., 6., 7.]], dtype=float32)>
```

As shown above, I have a workable solution, but I would expect a framework like [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) to have a more generic method to do this or at least a way to produce the intermediate tensor. The `tf.meshgrid` function seems to "almost" do what I want but the arguments are limited to rank 1 tensors.

Additionally, the above solution does not scale well. Some profiling indicates that the intermediate tensors are materialized, even in graph mode.